# or Minimizing a sum of a product

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I am trying to minimize a function and I was hoping that someone can point me in the right direction. I have tried using Lagrangian multipliers and experimenting with simple cases, but nothing has worked. I have also tried using Mathematica to no avail.

The function is this:

$$ \sum_{i}^n \prod_{j}^n \bigl ( 1 - b_{ij} x_{i} \bigr ) $$

with the following constraints:

$$ \sum_{i}^n xi = 1 $$  $$ 0 \lt x_{i} \lt 1 $$

If it's easier, I can work with this function instead:

$$ \prod_{i}^n \prod_{j}^n \bigl (1 - b_{ij} x_{i} \bigr ) $$

I would like to find a solution for $ x_i $ in terms of the constants $ b_{ij} $, but like I said, I am having some trouble. Since I already know the $ b_{ij} $, if I can just get it in a form that is easy to solve numerically, that would be great. In practice, $ n $ is roughly 10,000 - so it needs to be somewhat efficient.

I recently posted a similar question on Math StackExchange. I don't know best practices, so if you would like me to merge this question with that one, then I will try to do so. Thanks!

---

Update: I could also work with this function:

$$ \sum_i^n \prod_j^n \bigl ( 1 - b_{ij} x_j \bigr )  $$

Here, I substituted $x_j$ for $x_i$. Would this make things easier?

Comment: So, just to make sure, you mention "I would like to find a solution for $x_i$ in terms of...": are you given $b_{ij}$ or is that another parameter of optimization?

Comment: Also, are you trying to minimize this or maximize it? If maximizing, then this is convex as stated (in your second case) so there are fast, global solutions, if you're trying to minimize it, then I'd throw it into a general local solver, since the problem is pretty non-convex.

Comment: You goal function can be rewritten as $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$ where $f_i(\cdot)$ depends only on $x_i$. If you apply Lagrange multipliers method to it, you get
something like $f'_i(x_i) = \lambda$, a single $\lambda$ for all $i$. You can numerically compute an approximate inverse function for $f_i'(x)$ and then solve for $\lambda$ in the equation $\sum_{i=1}^n (f_i')^{-1}(\lambda) = 1$ using any root finder. In this way, you should be able to get a rough idea where the optimal $x_i$ are. If the approximation solution is still not good enough, you can figure out improvement later

Comment: I am given the $b_{ij}$. I am trying to minimize this function. Achille thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely look into it.